# How to find duplicates in a list of list of objects in java

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, duplicates

Let's say I have a data in an Array List of objects `compositeKeyValues = [["READ", "3GPP_ACCESS"], ["CREATE", "NON_3GPP"], ["READ", "3GPP_ACCESS"], ["MODIFY", "NON_3GPP"]]`

```
List<Object> compositeKeyValues = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to identify duplicate list inside that outer list, which contains identical values, like at index 0 and 2 the lists are identical. How can i identify something like that within the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you have:

```
List<List<String>> compositeKeyValues;
```

Lists are equal if they have the same elements in the same order - like your example.

Finding duplicate inner Lists is no different finding duplicates of other simpler types.

Here's one way:

```
List<List<String>> duplicates = compositeKeyValues.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().intValue() > 1)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code will work even if you leave the type of the List as `List<Object>`, except the result would also have type `List<Object>`. However, it's recommended, and more *useful*, to use a more specific type `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Although not recommended to use `List<Object>`. `List<List<String>>` is the way to go.

Comment: one more query, what's the exact import statements used here for using grouping by , identity() and counting() methods?

Comment: @misbhaafreen I've added the class names to code to make it clearer.  Use `import java.util.function.Function; import java.util.stream.Collectors;`. You can use `x -> x` instead of `Function.identity()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by not making the list of generic `Object` instances because this will make it so much more difficult to accomplish. Make the list of objects to be of a specific class instead. Then, your custom class must override Object's `equal()` and `hashCode()` methods.

The question is now, how is the easiest way to accomplish the actual removal of duplicates. The simple answer is to convert your `List` to a `Set`. I think something like this should work.

```
Set<SomeType> mySet = myList.findByType(type)
        .stream()
        .map(ClassName::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Keep in mind that the methods I mentioned will still need to be overridden. Most, if not all, modern IDEs have convenience methods to override `equals()` and hashCode()` methods.

Comment: i did try by comparing size of list and the set, but set is not eliminating these, and things are dynamic here, so i don't think i could make any specific class out of it.

Comment: @misbhaafreen Did you override `equals` and `hashCode` from `Object` class? My guess that you didn't. If you don't override these methods, there will be no way to determine if two distinct objects are identical in internal values. So, they won't be found and subsequently removed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to contribute an Array based solution even if the original question was about lists.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] data = { { "READ", "3GPP_ACCESS" }, { "CREATE", "NON_3GPP" }, { "READ", "3GPP_ACCESS" },
                { "MODIFY", "NON_3GPP" } };

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {// should not compare with itself and anything previously else
                                                        // there will be double findings like 0,2 and 2,0

                if (Arrays.equals(data[i], data[j])) // check for equality

                    System.out.println("Match found at " + i + " " + Arrays.toString(data[i]) + " and " + j + " "
                            + Arrays.toString(data[j]));

            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
java.util.List<String> list = Arrays.asList("READ", "3GPP_ACCESS","CREATE", "NON_3GPP","READ", "3GPP_ACCESS","MODIFY", "NON_3GPP");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j <list.size() ; j++) {
                if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){
                    System.out.println(list.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```